# Drawer with Fragments & back Button

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onbackpressed

So I am new to Android development, and have been trying to figure out how to be able to use the back button on a fragment and not close the app, but instead have it end up back at the first activity. Exactly how the Google Inbox works, and then if the back button is pushed again it would close the app. What I have going on is following code

https://github.com/g60madman/AndroidFragmentNavigationDrawer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/chrisrisner/fragmentsample/MainActivity.java

In the code it uses the default feature from Google Drawer to close the drawer if the drawer is open then exit out.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I have searched all over stack over flow but still coming up short with the suggestions people have offered as their code doesn't seem to work with in this code. Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your FragmentTransaction, you shoud use the method

> fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(yourTag)

before

> .commit()

That way, when you click the Back button, you go back and not close the app. 
Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

UPDATE:
line **41** and **121**:

> fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent,
>   fragment).commit();

should read

> fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
>   .replace(R.id.flContent,fragment)**.addToBackStack(null)**.commit();

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the info, since I am such a noob with Java I am not able to get this implemented. I have tried a ton of code changes but not sure where to put it into the code to make it work based on the code I linked too on the MainActivity.java

Comment: I updated the answer, check it out.
You need to change line 41 and line 121 on MainActivity.java